# Send email notification from Jenkins throwing error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-notifications, email-ext

I am trying to send email to users from Jenkins.

Below is how my configuration looks alike.

Without SSL 
[image: Without SSL]

With SSL

[image]

When enabling the SSL option, I am getting the below error

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted
```

While I am sure that credentials are valid.

While with the same credentials & without SSL if I try throws the error.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

How do I add my Gmail account to send email?

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this? I am trying the same for my Gmail with an SSL option, still no charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow less secure apps, you can do it by click below link

```
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
```

also, try this one

```
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
```

if it still not works try changing the password for Gmail.

ABove is tried and tested and it worked for me.